# What's the native wallpaper resolution of HTC One?

Tags: images, htc-one

I don't mean 1080p, but actual unscaled image size so when I set the wallpaper to an image with that size, it won't ask me to crop. It will fit without scaling.

Answer (score 0):

The screen resolution of the HTC One is [1080 x 1920 pixels](http://m.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php). This is also the same resolution when you trigger a screenshot on the phone.

Comment: Because of how Android's home screens work, the screen resolution is not the size you need for a wallpaper to be uncropped.